# Alert when any key is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the below javascript to alert when the user presses delete, backspace and space inside a textbox. I need to alert if any key is pressed inside the textbox and probably I can mention the keycode in the script for each key. But can anyone tell me if there is any other way to alert when any key is pressed?

```
 function doCheck() {
        var keyCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
        if ((keyCode == 8) || (keyCode == 46) || (keyCode == 32))
            alert('The column is readonly and is non-editable');
        event.returnValue = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this, Event Handlers `onkeypress`

```
onkeypress="KeyPressCheck(event)"
```

Javascript:

```
function KeyPressCheck(event){
   console.log('pressed::'+ event.keyCode);
}
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onkeypress

Answer (score 1):

```
 function doCheck(event)
```

and pass event where you are using this function

for eg.

```
 onclick="doCheck(event)"
```

Comment: onclick="doCheck(event)" (missing "c") ;)

Comment: How is this upvoted? The OP wants to trap keypresses and this is using a (misspelled) click handler...?

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery to attach the event, otherwise you will have to add `on` handler attributes to *every* element manually. Try this:

```
$('.texboxes').keypress(function(e) {
    if ((e.which == 8) || (e.which == 46) || (e.which == 32)) {
        alert('The column is readonly and is non-editable');
        event.returnValue = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery [Keyup Event handler](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) to find which key is press.

```
$( "#SelectorId" ).keyup(function( event ) {
    //check for which key is pressed.
    if ((event.which== 8) || (event.which== 46) || (event.which== 32)){
       alert("Some message");  
       event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Why to use `keyup` event :

keydown and keyup provide a code indicating which key is pressed, while keypress indicates which character was entered. For example, a lowercase "a" will be reported as 65 by keydown and keyup, but as 97 by keypress. An uppercase "A" is reported as 65 by all events. Because of this distinction, when catching special keystrokes such as arrow keys, .keydown() or .keyup() is a better choice.